# 9.8 Mathematical Analysis by Apostol

Tags: real-analysis

Can someone please explain to me the 2nd point in question below?

[image]

In point 2 what does the condition $|f_k(x)-f(x)|<\delta$ means, is it true for all $k$ or does this $k$ depends on $x$?

Comment: Well, $k$ cannot depend on $x$, right? You have $k$ first, and then you select your $x$ from the set $B \left( x_0 \right)$. Although, it is clearly written that it does depend on $x_0$.

Comment: That's what confusing me, if we ignore the hint than point 2 looks really weird

Comment: But it is given that the condition (ii) holds for **all** $k$.